# Regular Expression to match specific string

Tags: asp.net, regex

RegEx has always been my Achilles' heel. I am writing web app, where user will input his identifier. I'm using `RegexValidator` to validate this input.

The identifier should be something like this:

```
TN-In-PL-KW-2012-1234
```

And this is how the identifier is built:

- first two letters are always `TN`
- followed by hyphen
- then two letters, that are either: `In`, `Te`, `Yo` or `Et`
- hyphen
- two uppercase letters
- another hyphen
- another two uppercase letters
- hyphen
- four digits, that are a year, so something between 1970 and 2012 (I can ignore that as long as there are 4 digits)
- hyphen
- ordinal number that can have from 1 to 4 digits

Please help me writing RegEx to match this identifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^TN-(In|Te|Yo|Et)-[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-\d{1,4}$
```

Just as a comment, I recommend you [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) if you want to improve your regex skills, it's a simple and practical page to have in mind when you need to work with regex

Answer (score 2):

`TN-(In|Te|Yo|Et)-([A-Z]{2}-){2}(19[7-9][0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-2])-[0-9]{1,4}`

Answer (score 1):

```
TN-((In)|(Te)|(Yo)|(Et))-[A-Z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}-\d{1,4}
```