# Using Visual Studio 2013 regular expression find - how to invalidate multiple prefixes

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to find the "symbol" all in a bunch of C#, XML, and JS files. My project is huge and doing a naive search for "all" results in over 8,000 lines found so I'm trying to eliminate some of them.

For example, I don't want to match on "call" or "balloon" or "Balloon" (those are UX element styles.

Looking at the using Regular Expressions MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I found out how to invalidate on one of those but I can't figure out how to do it on multiple and make it case-insensitive.

I started off using:

```
(?!c)all
```

And that filtered out call and things like that but I can't get one to filter out multiple to work.

```
(?!b|c)all
```

Is the form I've been playing around with, trying to get it to ignore balloon. Ideally I could do something like (warning! - invalid regex below)

```
(?!b|c|B|C|)all
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great. The reason why I'm not looking for all surrounded by spaces is because I don't know if the reference I'm looking for is going to be:

```
.All
.all
("All")
(all)
```

and etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with lookarounds, but you want to use a character class with it. (More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

There are convenient shorthand character classes, like `\w`, to represent common classes. `\w` for example represents all alphanumeric characters and is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

`\b` represents a "word boundary," or in other words the beginning/end of the string and a boundary between a word character and a non-word character. It is zero-length and doesn't won't match any characters.

Here are some examples using a word boundary, positive lookaround, and negative lookaround respectively:

`\b[aA][lL][lL]\b`

`(?<=[^\w])[aA][lL][lL](?=[^\w])`

`(?<!\w)[aA][lL][lL](?!\w)`

Basically, these will find case-insensitive matches of "all" that are surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters. If you want to exclude certain surrounding characters, you can replace `\w` with your own character class (e.g. to exclude surrounding quote marks, use `[A-Za-z0-9_"]` instead of `\w`).

Answer (score 2):

The following regex: `(?<!(b|c))all` (with the IgnoreCase flag)

With the following input: `ball all stall .all( "ALL"`

Has the following matches: `ball [all] st[all] .[all]( "[ALL]"`

Comment: I didn't realize the ignore case flag, carried over to the regex search. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried: **[aA][lL][lL]\b**

any version of "all" or "ALL" anchored at a word/non-word boundary

Here is another reference..
[Regular Expression to match specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352870/regular-expression-to-match-specific-string)

Comment: A simpler version for VS2013: search for `\bALL\b`, don't check "case-sensitive".

Comment: It's a good way to get `all` as a word, as he shows in the example of matches he expects to find, but its not clear whether the regex should match for `tall` or not (its not `call`, nor `balloon`, nor `Balloon`)